# How does ARIMA function know which lag to use?

Tags: forecasting, arima, lags

Say for an ARIMA function with orders, ARIMA(3,1,1). How does ARIMA know which lag to consider. It may not be always  be lags at t-1, t-2, t-3. It could be t-4, t-15,t-22.

Answer (score 1):

It usually makes little sense to include lags at $t-4$, $t-15$ and $t-22$ without also including lags of lower orders. This would be equivalent to setting a lot of AR (or MA) coefficients to zero.

The only case where this does make sense is a seasonal time series. For instance, I am currently working with data where the ACF shows clear peaks at lags 7, 14, 21, 28 and 35. Yes, these are daily data with weekly autoregressive behavior. In such a situation, the classical approach is to use seasonal differencing and fit a SARIMA model.

Comment: Do you mean to say that coefficients of higher lags tend to be quite low compared to lower order. Like coeff of lags at 7 is lot smaller to Lag 1? If so why?

Comment: It's rather that I find it hard to think of a data generating process that is influenced by lag $t-4$, but not by $t-1$, $t-2$ and $t-3$. (Unless, as I wrote, there is seasonality involved.) There is no theoretical point here; you can always *simulate* such a process. I just don't think it corresponds to anything in reality.